# pure Bash way to trim

Tags: strings, bash, io

How can I improve this? I added the `while read` loop to handle preceding newlines.

```
trim()
{
    # skip leading whitespace
    while read -r string; do [[ -n "${string}" ]] && break; done
    string="${string#"${string%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
    string="${string%"${string##*[![:space:]]}"}"
    printf "${string}"
}
```

Usage:

```
$ echo "   hello   " | trim; echo
hello
$ echo "

  hello multi-line
   " | trim
hello multi-line
$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment is misleading - the function does skip leading whitespace-only lines, but it also removes all lines after the first non-whitespace.

I would simplify to read all of the input into `string`, and then remove the whitespace:

```
    string=$(cat)
    string="${string#"${string%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
```

Don't make the result the format-string for `printf` - any % in the input will be substituted (e.g. `trim <<<%d` results in `0` as output).  Instead, use `%s` as the format string:

```
   printf %s "$string"
```

---

## Modified code

```
trim()
{
    string=$(cat)
    string=${string#${string%%[![:space:]]*}}
    printf %s "${string%${string##*[![:space:]]}}"
}
```

And some improved tests:

```
tests=(
    '   hello   '
    '

  hello  multi-line  ''
   '
    '

  two
  lines
   
   '
    '%d'

    '   '

    '
'
)

for s in "${tests[@]}"
do
    printf '%s\n^%s$\n\n' "${s@Q}" "$(trim <<<"$s")"
done
```